# Python SSH Library

Tags: python, ssh

I have to use a bash command `ssh www.example.com` in my python code. What is the best library? I am having a hard time translating this to paramiko. 
I have also tried subprocess library but neither of these are working for me.

```python
subprocess.check_call(
"ssh www.example.com".format(title, description),
shell=True)

ssh=paramiko.SSHClient
def __init__(self, name):
ssh www.example.com
```

can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? Is there a better library to directly translate the bash command to python, in this case ssh? 
just to give more context, I have hitting a ssh url that generates a password which then I need to feed back into my code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Questions requesting a library recommendation are explicitly off-topic here; see #4 in the "some questions are still off-topic" list at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. That said, [`paramiko`](http://www.paramiko.org/) is perhaps the most long-lived / well-established SSH library for Python. It implements the protocol natively, so it isn't running any bash commands at all.

Comment: Maybe a narrow question showing how you tried to use paramiko and how it failed -- including details on how to reproduce that failure -- would be more useful? Be sure that the code is a [mcve] -- meaning the shortest thing that can be copied-and-pasted by someone to see the same failure that the question is about, rather than failing due to typos/syntax/other unrelated errors.

Comment: Thanks you for all this information, wasn't aware of the off topic stuff. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used something like this:

```
c = ("ssh example.com")
ssh = subprocess.Popen(c, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,     stdin=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True, shell=True)
```

You can read the output with `ssh.stdout`.

Comment: Thank you!!! I think this works? When I run it on the ssh command in the terminal, it then prompts me to enter a password before it gives me the output I need. Any idea how to add that to this? Where python feeds the password to the terminal? Not sure if that makes sense.
someone suggested just writing it in a bash file and having python call that file, but I would hate to have two different languages, it's just ugly.

Comment: Using `ssh.stdin.write("password")` should work.
But I would recommend to use `pass = getpass.getpass()` to get the password and then use `ssh.stdin.write(pass)` because hardcoding passwords is bad. 

Or even better, you could use an ssh key.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, super super helpful.  The thing is when I run 
c = ("ssh example.com")
ssh = subprocess.Popen(c, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,     stdin=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True, shell=True)

it somehow presses enter after it runs? can't figure out why it's doing that. Basically when I run that in bash, it asks for my password before it generates a password for me. However, when I run the python code, it presses enter before letting me enter a password.

Comment: just to clarify, when I run the python file with c= ssh I get: 
$ Enter PIN for 'PIV_II (PIV Card Holder pin)':
Password:
Password:
versus, I would just like it to stop at pin and that way I can put in the code where the user can enter their pin, where it then generates the password which then I can feed into another program.